# Why there is welding on some iron transformers' core?

Tags: transformer, core, iron-core

[image]
(This photo isn't mine!)

Why there is welding on some iron transformers' core?
is it only for holding the laminations together?

## edit

can we repair or rewind this kind of transformers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done on all MOT's (Microwave Oven Tfmr )to keep the kitchen quiet... as in tech terms reduce acoustic noise from vibration from magnetic forces on the grain oriented silicate coated thin laminations of high permeability steel and partial noises from some magnetostiction forces in the magnetic particles at the expense of some efficiency losses.

Comment: it's probably also cheaper than clamping! Everything about a MO is lowest possible cost.

Comment: This kind of welding is already done many years. It keeps noise or hum at a low level and is les expensive than using schrews. The extra eddycurrent losses you get free of charge with this construction

Comment: The weld is more rigid than the pressure of even hardened steel bolts.  (screws are not strong enough) The cost of consumer choices of quiet vs efficiency of low duty cycle useage, make this choice suitable only for MOT's. The cost of the bolts may be significant, but still not better in performance.

Comment: Weld can be ground off. This is usually done when people are using the core as the basis for some other transformer. eg spot welder. Note that they usually have an unusual magnetic shunt path which may make them worse or better depending on application.

Answer (score 2):

> edit
> can we repair or rewind this kind of transformers?

There is lots of information on the internet related to MOT modification. Most projects involve leaving the primary winding intact and replacing the secondary winding without removing the "I" part of the core. If the "I" is removed, some recommend cutting the weld with a thin blade rather than grinding.

**[Here](https://moam.info/reuse-of-post-consumer-e-waste-for-low-cost-the-microformer_5adbfb997f8b9a495e8b46dc.html)** is a technical paper that may be a little more difficult to find than the usual project descriptions.
RM: Link updated March 2022. Can be viewed full screen and can be downloaded.

Comment: RM: Link updated March 2022. Can be viewed full screen and can be downloaded.